# Connecting Thunderbird to Exchange via DavMail

Tags: java, connection, exchange-server, thunderbird

> Sending of password did not succeed.
>   Mail server localhost responded:
>   Unable to get mail folder at
>   /exchange/name.surname@domain.com/,
>   Webdav not available on Exchange
>   server

This is the message the Thunderbird (and DavMail) show to me when i try to connect.
I've set thunderbird as the DavMail guide suggest.

Setting in DavMail OWA field the correct https url (i mean "https://mail.domain.it/owa") but something goes wrong.

The credential specified in thunderbird seems correct. Using the same on the web access work perfectly.

Here an extract of the DavMail logs:

```
2010-09-16 10:21:34,585 INFO  [main] davmail  - DavMail Gateway 3.8.4-1432 listening on SMTP port 1025 POP port 1110 IMAP port 1143 CALDAV port 1080 LDAP port 1389 
2010-09-16 10:21:35,084 DEBUG [CheckRelease] davmail.DavGateway  - DavMail released version: 3.8.4-1432
2010-09-16 10:21:47,711 DEBUG [davmail.pop.PopServer] davmail  - Connection from /127.0.0.1 on port 1110
2010-09-16 10:21:48,471 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - Found permanently accepted certificate, hash F6:FF:75:7E:55:61:52:9C:77:6D:B1:21:C3:38:E8:2C:13:C1:A4:C8
2010-09-16 10:21:48,534 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - Test configuration status: 301
2010-09-16 10:21:48,547 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - > +OK DavMail POP ready at Thu Sep 16 10:21:48 CEST 2010
2010-09-16 10:21:48,551 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - < CAPA
2010-09-16 10:21:48,554 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - > +OK Capability list follows
2010-09-16 10:21:48,554 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - > TOP
2010-09-16 10:21:48,555 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - > USER
2010-09-16 10:21:48,555 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - > UIDL
2010-09-16 10:21:48,556 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - > .
2010-09-16 10:21:48,558 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - < USER USERNAME
2010-09-16 10:21:48,559 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - > +OK USER : USERNAME
2010-09-16 10:21:48,561 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - < PASS ********
2010-09-16 10:21:48,755 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - executeFollowRedirects(https://mail.DOMAIN.it/owa)
2010-09-16 10:21:48,788 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - executeFollowRedirects: /owa/ redirectCount:1
2010-09-16 10:21:48,836 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - executeFollowRedirects: https://mail.DOMAIN.it/owa/auth/logon.aspx?url=https://mail.DOMAIN.it/owa/&reason=0 redirectCount:2
2010-09-16 10:21:48,893 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - Form based authentication detected
2010-09-16 10:21:48,916 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - Detected script based logon, redirect to form at https://mail.DOMAIN.it/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.DOMAIN.it%2fowa%2f
2010-09-16 10:21:48,917 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - executeFollowRedirects(https://mail.DOMAIN.it/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=https%3a%2f%2fmail.DOMAIN.it%2fowa%2f)
2010-09-16 10:21:48,980 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - executeFollowRedirects(https://mail.DOMAIN.it/owa/auth/owaauth.dll)
2010-09-16 10:21:49,003 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - executeFollowRedirects: https://mail.DOMAIN.it/owa/ redirectCount:1
2010-09-16 10:21:49,134 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - Current user email is NAME.SURNAME@guest.DOMAIN.it, alias is NAME.SURNAME, mailPath is /exchange/NAME.SURNAME@guest.DOMAIN.it/
2010-09-16 10:21:49,402 ERROR [PopConnection-53324] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - 401 Unauthorized at /exchange/NAME.SURNAME@guest.DOMAIN.it/
2010-09-16 10:21:49,403 ERROR [PopConnection-53324] davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession  - Unable to get mail folder at /exchange/NAME.SURNAME@guest.DOMAIN.it/, Webdav not available on Exchange server
2010-09-16 10:21:49,403 ERROR [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - Unable to get mail folder at /exchange/NAME.SURNAME@guest.DOMAIN.it/, Webdav not available on Exchange server
davmail.exception.DavMailAuthenticationException: Unable to get mail folder at /exchange/NAME.SURNAME@guest.DOMAIN.it/, Webdav not available on Exchange server
 at davmail.exchange.dav.DavExchangeSession.getWellKnownFolders(DavExchangeSession.java:716)
 at davmail.exchange.dav.DavExchangeSession.buildSessionInfo(DavExchangeSession.java:429)
 at davmail.exchange.ExchangeSession.<init>(ExchangeSession.java:181)
 at davmail.exchange.dav.DavExchangeSession.<init>(DavExchangeSession.java:421)
 at davmail.exchange.ExchangeSessionFactory.getInstance(ExchangeSessionFactory.java:117)
 at davmail.pop.PopConnection.run(PopConnection.java:137)
2010-09-16 10:21:49,405 DEBUG [PopConnection-53324] davmail  - > -ERR Unable to get mail folder at /exchange/NAME.SURNAME@guest.DOMAIN.it/, Webdav not available on Exchange server
```

I've found something about adding an option to info.plist but i don't know enough of java to understand what to do and where to do it... if someone can help this will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

@thecrius, since Webdav is not available on your Exchange server, you could try using the EWS (Exchange Web Services) instead. Here's a [thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/davmail/forums/forum/644057/topic/3797643) from the DavMail forums that might help.